# Pandas duplicated rows with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Hello I have a dataframe that contains duplicates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1], 
                   'name':['Hamburg','Hamburg','Hamburg'], 
                   'country':['Germany','Germany',None],
                   'state':[None,None,'Hamburg']})
```

removing the duplicates with `df.drop_duplicates()` returns:

[image]

How can I configure `drop_duplicates` such that only one row is left, that contains all the information?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('id')`?

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang. I didn't formulate my question correctly. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you have no row with all the information at once, you can use `groupby` and `first` but first `fillna` None with `np.nan` to work with missing values:

```
print (df.fillna(value=np.nan).groupby('id').first())
       name  country    state
id                           
1   Hamburg  Germany  Hamburg
```

Answer (score 1):

In your very special case, here's my proposal :

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2], 
                   'name':['Hamburg','Hamburg','Hamburg','Paris','Paris'], 
                   'country':['Germany','Germany',None, None, 'France'],
                   'state':[None,None,'Hamburg', 'Paris', None]})

df_result=pandas.DataFrame()
for id in df['id'].unique().tolist() :
    df_subset=df[df['id']==id].copy(deep=True)
    df_subset.sort_values(by=['id','name','country','state'],inplace=True)
    df_subset.bfill(inplace=True)
    df_subset.ffill(inplace=True)
    df_subset.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
    df_result=df_result.append(df_subset)

df=df_result

Out[18]: 
   id     name  country    state
0   1  Hamburg  Germany  Hamburg
4   2    Paris   France    Paris
```

Subsetting the records will avoid ffill or bfill to fill adjacent but different id records.

Regards